# Polymer - items in DOM-IF returning null in first call

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm writing because I have problem with understanding how Polymer ready and elements exactly works. I'm using Polymer 2.0.

In my template I have this code:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{isExpanded}}">
        <div id="drop-down-list" >
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{employees}}">
                <button on-click="onDropDownItemClick" class="button-style items">{{item}}</button>
            </template>
        </div>
    </template>
```

On start the `isExpandend` is `false`. So the buttons are hidden, or even not created?

Then in some function I switch `isExpandend` to `true` and I want to update some styles in that way:

```
var items = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.items');
            for(var i=0; i< items.length; i++){
                items[i].style.height = itemHeight;
            }
```

The problem is - this solution only works with second or more entry to this function.
So when I call this function first time, items are null, and nothing changed, but when I call second time and more items = [], and code works good.

What should I do to repair this bug?

Should I do something with "async" I find this on stack but i have no idea how to use it.

Comment: This is correct behaviour from Polymer, but to be able to help, please share your component props and the function that updates the `isExpanded`.

Answer (score 0):

I found one possible solution for this problem.
I added id too template with dom-if

and before this JS code I write:

```
this.$["templateID"].render();
```

This is working, but I don't know it is good?

Comment: This is probably not the right answer to your problem.

Comment: You should probably start by checking how you're updating `isExpandend` (are using `this.set('isExpanded', true)` or something else) and not walk this route. As mentioned earlier please share the code or create a plunker so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

How do you perform the switch of `isExpanded`? Usually when something doesn't work at first but then updates later on interaction that means that you mutated the value incorrectly and maybe you should be using `set` or `push` api's to notify about changes.

Do you think you can create a plunker with the example?

Answer (score 0):

Correct behavior for Polymer, the items are not added to the DOM so do not have a height.

Possibly you can add a [dom-change event](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-change)

But more ideal is that you just style the height of the individual elements using CSS. Why set it in a for loop?